Don't understand marginfi::instruction::xxxx
In https://github.com/mrgnlabs/marginfi-v2.git project, using anchor 0.29.0.
I noticed that in the test-utils folder, all the calls to the instruction functions in marginfi::instruction::xxxxx why are they going as structures? They are clearly in the form of functions in programs/marginfi/src/lib.rs. I'm wondering if I'm lacking some knowledge in the ANCHOR framework?
For exmaple:
pub async fn make_lending_account_start_flashloan_ix(&self, end_index: u64) -> Instruction {
        Instruction {
            program_id: marginfi::id(),
            accounts: marginfi::accounts::LendingAccountStartFlashloan {
                marginfi_account: self.key,
                signer: self.ctx.borrow().payer.pubkey(),
                ixs_sysvar: sysvar::instructions::id(),
            }
            .to_account_metas(Some(true)),
            data: marginfi::instruction::LendingAccountStartFlashloan { end_index }.data(),
        }
    }

When I click on the jump definition for marginfi::instruction::LendingAccountStartFlashloan, it shows it as a function.
pub fn lending_account_start_flashloan(
        ctx: Context<LendingAccountStartFlashloan>,
        end_index: u64,
    ) -> MarginfiResult {
        marginfi_account::lending_account_start_flashloan(ctx, end_index)
    }


The test-utils folder is for testing in Rust, run the test-program.sh script in scripts to execute these.
The namespace marginfi::instruction is generated by Anchor. For each instruction specified in lib.rs, it makes a struct with all the input arguments, and you can use this to serialize an instruction. Typically you would only use these for offchain testing, building a client in Rust, etc.
For example, the Rust client (clients/rust/marginfi-cli) also uses these to serialize ix data. E.g.:
    let mut ix = Instruction {
        program_id: marginfi::id(),
        accounts: //...
        }
        .to_account_metas(Some(true)),
        data: marginfi::instruction::LendingPoolCollectBankFees {}.data(),
    };

